# Resize sidebar in document viewer (PDF file)

Tags: pdf, evince

I an unable to find a way of resizing the document viewer sidebar while viewing PDF file on Ubuntu.

[image]

Is there a way?

Comment: The side-bar should be resizable by drag. Have 3.28.4 and here it is no problem.Could be a bug in your version. You could also try this: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1032#note_368948

Comment: Attempted to build 3.36.10 from git-repo, but configure gives some weird errors. If all fails you could test out qpdfview. I use that as main PDF viewer these days.

Comment: You could try listing the settings with `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Evince.Default` and changing the size with, for example, `gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default sidebar-size 300`. I don't have your version, so perhaps this has changed too.

Comment: @meuh The setting change affected the sidebar size but strangely it only changed it for certain files. The books still have the narrow sidebar but random PDF files (user manuals etc) show a wider sidebar. Weird.

Comment: @ibuprofen what a stupid thing. Turns out that it actually *is* resizable by dragging but the resize handle area is very small and on top of that the mouse cursor never changes to double headed arrow contrary to developer's claim here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1032#note_368948 . Thanks a lot, I can read table of contents now.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. It could perhaps be affected by UI themes, cursor themes etc. IDK. Can not find anything about it here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/blob/master/NEWS - thought I have not looked that hard. Nor in commits, bug reports, pull requests etc. You *could* open a ticket https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues In 3.28.4 the cursor changes and the trigger area is reasonably wide.